# python - Loop iteration simplify with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been coding for a while in python but now I'm facing some serious code performance issues (because of loops for iterating over matrixes) and I've decided to use numpy to speed it up and to learn a bit more.

I'm still getting the hang of masking and that's why I'm here. This is the code I'm trying to simplify. I'm using `outSum` as an accumulator then on the values for both gX and gY aren't zero at the same position, I run `testPossibleCentersFormula` and store the accumulated result in `outSum`

```
outSum = np.zeros((len(gX),len(gX[0])), np.uint8)
outCols, outRows = outSum.shape

for y in range(len(gX)):
    Xr = gX[y]
    Yr = gY[y]
    for x in range(len(Xr)):
        grX = Xr[x]
        grY = Yr[x]
        if (grX == 0.0 and grY == 0.0):
            continue
        outSum = testPossibleCentersFormula(x, y, weight, grX, grY, outSum)
```

I've tried to mask it like this

```
gX_zero = gX[:,0] == 0
gY_zero = gY[:,0] == 0
gXgY_zero = np.logical_not(np.logical_and(gX_zero, gY_zero))
```

But I don't know how to call my function after that.

I'm looking forward to also simplify the `testPossibleCentersFormula` function itself, since it lacks numpy

```
def testPossibleCentersFormula(x, y, weight, gx, gy, out):
#for all possible centers
for cy in range(len(out)):
    Or = out[cy]
    Wr = weight[cy]
    for cx in range(len(Or)):
        if (x == cx and y == cy):
            continue
        #create a vector from the possible center to the gradient origin
        dx = x - cx;
        dy = y - cy;

        #normalize d
        magnitude = math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
        dx = dx / magnitude
        dy = dy / magnitude

        dotProduct = dx*gx + dy*gy
        dotProduct = max(0.0, dotProduct)

        #square and multiply by the weight

        if (kEnableWeight):
            Or[cx] += dotProduct * dotProduct * (Wr[cx]/kWeightDivisor)
        else:
            Or[cx] += dotProduct * dotProduct
return out
```

Here the problem is that I don't really know what to do with those indexes as I need them if I want to operate with the matrixes element-wise with numpy.

Thanks beforehand!

EDIT:
The comment from hpaulj got me thinking and I've come to simplify `testPossibleCentersFormula` to something like this:

```
def testPossibleCentersFormulaEX(x, y, weight, gx, gy, out):
    cx = np.arange(len(out))
    cy = np.arange(len(out[0]))

    dx = x - cx
    dy = y - cy

    mags = np.sqrt(np.square(dx) + np.square(dy))
    dx = np.divide(dx, mags)
    dy = np.divide(dx, mags)

    dotProduct = dx * gx + dy * dy

    np.maximum(0.0, dotProduct)

    if(kEnableWeight):
        out += np.multiply(np.square(dotProduct),(weight/kWeightDivisor))
    else:
        out += np.square(dotProduct)
    return out
```

Now the problem is that of course, dx and dy don't have the same length and therefore I can't operate them like that. What am I missing here? Oh, and still no clue with the first piece of code.

Comment: If you could iterate `cx` and `cy` in any order (or in parallel) (and `len(Or)` is the same for all `cy`), then writing that `testPossibleCentersFormula` using `numpy` should be straight forward.   Take a small case, say 4x3, where `cy` and `cx` are `[0,1,2,3]` and `[0,1,2]`, and try to express the calculation in terms of those whole arrays, not just indivdually.

Comment: I've come to think of something thanks to your tip, but I'm a bit stuck. Could you push me in the right direction again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

n,m = 4,5
out = np.zeros((n,m))
x, y = 1,2
gx,gy=.1,.3
weight = False
def test(x,y, weight, gx, gy, out):
    N,M=np.meshgrid(np.arange(n),np.arange(m), indexing='ij')
    # N,M shape match out
    dy = y-N
    dx = x-M
    mag = mag=np.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy))
    mag[mag==0]=1  # take care of div by 0 problem
    dx = dx/mag
    dy = dy/mag
    dotp=dx*gx + dy*gy
    dotp=np.maximum(0,dotp)
    out[:] = dotp
test(x,y,weight, gx,gy,out)
print(out)
```

produces an array like:

```
In [121]: run stack31064314.py
[[ 0.31304952  0.3         0.2236068   0.14142136  0.08320503]
 [ 0.28284271  0.3         0.14142136  0.04472136  0.        ]
 [ 0.1         0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

I developed this interactively in Ipython - creating the `meshgrid` arrays (to represent cx and cy in 2d), changing to `ij` indexing to match `out`.  A test calc also helped think of how to address the `0` value.  Likewise I found by trial and error that I want `maximum` not `max`.

It's not guaranteed to be right, since I don't have a working copy of your original function.  But since it runs and produces the correct shaped output, it's a good starting point.

This is an intermediate version:

```
def testPossibleCentersFormula(x, y, weight, gx, gy, out):
    out = np.empty((n,m))
    cy = np.arange(out.shape[0])
    cx = np.arange(out.shape[1])

    dx = x - cx  # len m
    dy = y - cy  # len n
    magnitude = np.sqrt((dx*dx)[None,:]+(dy*dy)[:,None]) # (n,m) array

    dx = dx[None,:] / magnitude
    dy = dy[:,None] / magnitude
    # problem one value of magnitude will be 0, (x,y)

    dotProduct = dx*gx + dy*gy  # gx,gy scalars
    dotProduct = np.max(0, dotProduct)  # make sure it is right max
    # ie clip dotProduct a 0
    dotProduct = dotProduct * dotProduct
    if kEnableWeight:
        # Wr - (n,m) array
        dotProduct *= (Wr/kWeightDivisor)
    Out[:,:] =  dotProduct
```

I didn't get it running, but it helped me identify the issues.

Comment: Gonna test it now and tell ya if it's OK, but for now, thanks a bunch

Comment: I created a hybrid version from your two pieces of cose. Seems to work fine. now I have to study your solution a bit more.  Thanks again. Marking it as answer. Can you give me some more tips for the firs piece of code?